# accessing to the children package variable from the base class by using only $self or ref($self)

Tags: perl

I have the following problem, may be I am trying to solve it in a bad way so if you tell me how to do it in a right way I would be very grateful!

I have a base class which has a method which I want to access to a package variable based on real object class (ref($self)).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $var = SubClass->new();
$var->method();

package BaseClass;

sub new { construct... }
sub method { 
   my $self = shift;

   # in this method I wan to get values from 'our %VAR' of the children class or ref($self) class, something like that:
   return ${ref($self)::VAR}{k1}; 

   # of course I can create a method and do it in the following way but I am not sure that it's a good idea
   return $self->get_var()->{k1};
}
sub get_var { die "Imaplement in children"; }

package SubClass;

use base 'BaseClass';

our %VAR = (k1 => 'smth', k2 => 'smth', ...);
sub get_var { return \%VAR } # don't like this idea

1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `%{ref($self)::VAR}` solution may sometimes be the easiest, although a paranoid programmer would include some checks:

```
# Accessing %__PACKAGE__::VAR:
# I hope that I'm not in a subclass,
#    because that would change the value reported by `ref($self)`
#    and I can't be bothered to search @ISA manually...

unless (defined ref $self) {
   die "\$self is not a reference!";
}
if (ref $self ~~ [qw/SCALAR ARRAY HASH
   CODE REF GLOB LVALUE FORMAT IO VSTRING Regexp /]) {
   die "\$self is not an object!";
}
no strict 'refs'; # Hehe, I can't use strict here :S
unless (%{ref($self).'::VAR'}) {
   warn "Umm, this hash is empty."
      . "I don't know if I just created it, or it is meant to be that way.";
}
return ${ref($self).'::VAR'}{k1};
```

In conclusion, using an accessor method does not only save us repetition, it is also safer, less hackish and far more object oriented:

```
sub return_var {
   # We know that we are in the right package.
   # We know we are accessing the correct hash.
   # It is irrelevant whether I call this method
   #    from the package/class or from an object.
   # And I'm glad to take the method performance penalty
   #    in exchange for clear code.
   return \%VAR;
}
```

In conclusion #2, there is more than one way to do it. And in Perl, there is no "right" way. Although you might understand why I find the second solution more elegant.

Comment: Thanks Amon! I am going to use the second solution. It's really more clearer than the first one.
Also the first one looks very haskish and difficult to understand by others who will support this code.